# Python sending email too slow

Tags: python, performance, email, smtp

I have the script below which I'm using to send say 10 messages myself<->myself. However, I've noticed that Python really takes a while to do that. Last year I needed a system to send about 200 emails with attachments and text and I implemented it with msmtp + bash. As far as I remember it was much faster.

Moving the while loop inside (around the smtp_serv.sendmail(sender, recepient, msg) function yields similar results).

Am I doing something wrong? Surely it can't be slower than bash + msmtp (and I'm only sending a 'hi' message, no attachments).

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.1

def sendmail(recepient,  msg):

    import smtplib

    # Parameters
    sender = 'login@gmail.com'
    password = 'password'
    smtpStr = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    smtpPort = 587
    # /Parameters

    smtp_serv = smtplib.SMTP(smtpStr, smtpPort)
    smtp_serv.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
    smtp_serv.starttls()
    smtp_serv.ehlo()

    recepientExists = smtp_serv.verify(recepient)
    if recepientExists[0] == 250:
        smtp_serv.login(sender, password)
        try:
            smtp_serv.sendmail(sender, recepient, msg)
        except smtplib.SMTPException:
            print(recepientExists[1])
    else:
        print('Error',   recepientExists[0], ':',  recepientExists[1])

    smtp_serv.quit()

for in in range(10):
    sendmail('receiver@gmail.com',  'hi')
```

Comment: Seeing the Received: headers of a sample message might reveal blocks outside of your application, such as a server greylisting you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this script it takes five times more time to setup SMTP connection (5 seconds) than to send a e-mail (1 second) so it could make sense to setup a single connection and send several e-mails instead of creating the connection each time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import smtplib    
from contextlib import contextmanager
from datetime   import datetime
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from netrc      import netrc
from timeit     import default_timer as timer

@contextmanager
def logined(sender, password, smtp_host='smtp.gmail.com', smtp_port=587):
    start = timer(); smtp_serv = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_port, timeout=10)
    try: # make smtp server and login
        smtp_serv.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
        smtp_serv.starttls()
        smtp_serv.ehlo()
        print('smtp setup took (%.2f seconds passed)' % (timer()-start,))
        start = timer(); smtp_serv.login(sender, password)
        print('login took %.2f seconds' % (timer()-start,))
        start = timer(); yield smtp_serv
    finally:
        print('Operations with smtp_serv took %.2f seconds' % (timer()-start,))
        start = timer(); smtp_serv.quit()
        print('Quiting took %.2f seconds' % (timer()-start,))

smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
login, _, password = netrc().authenticators(smtp_host)
with logined(login, password, smtp_host) as smtp_serv:
    for i in range(10):
        msg = MIMEText('#%d timestamp %s' % (i, datetime.utcnow()))
        msg['Subject'] = 'test #%d' % i
        msg['From'] = login
        msg['To'] = login
        smtp_serv.send_message(msg)
```

#### Output

```
smtp setup took (5.43 seconds passed)
login took 0.40 seconds
Operations with smtp_serv took 9.84 seconds
Quiting took 0.05 seconds
```

If your Python version doesn't have `.send_message()` then you could use:

```
smtp_serv.sendmail(from, to, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Please don't use `;` to write several commands on one line, it makes code unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @taleinat: Just ignore `start = timer();` and read the rest. I don't like `;` too but I don't like a scrolling window inside another scrolling window even more.

Comment: I read the code just fine, but remember that many novice programmers read the answers posted here. In your answer, specifically the line `start = timer(); yield smtp_serv` "hides" the `yield` statement, making the context manager hard to understand. More generally, the coding style of the answer and the number of advanced tools used make this answer difficult to comprehend to all but experienced Python programmers. Compare your code to that posted in the question -- the difference is quite dramatic! I recommend posted the simplest, clearest code possible in answer here.

Comment: I should have ready the comments before submitting an edit proposal regarding the `;`. Please disregard it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

You are opening the connection to the SMTP server and then closing it for each email. It would be more efficient to keep the connection open while sending all of the emails.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. That's why I had the loop inside - around the smtp_serv.sendmail function. It had similar performance. If you meant something different please elaborate but I think that's what you meant.

Comment: That is what I meant. Any reason you thought it would be better to move the loop outside as you have above? For sending 10 emails I imagine the overhead of opening the connection is probably very small but I would expect that as you approach 100s of emails it would become noticeable. Though admittedly I don't have any benchmarks in front of me.

Comment: No reason really, I just forgot that I'm opening and closing it. I immediately corrected it but as it didn't show any noticeable effect I though it must be something different. The smtp_serv.sendmail function takes about a second or so which is very slow.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this comes very late, but I think it is relevant for the matter.
I had the same issue recently and realized, by searching around, that the call to connect the SMTP server may be very time consuming due to issues with domain name resolution, since the SMTP server performs a reverse lookup to verify the connecting client.

In my case this call was taking around 1 minute!:

```
s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
```

Solution was to fix the domain name resolution on the Linux box. After that, connection became very quick.

Hope this may be of help.

Comment: Hi, how do you fix the domain name resolution on the Linux box?

Comment: In my case, the SMTP server was inside the LAN of my Lab. The "hack" was to add the client's host name and address in the /etc/hosts file of the SMTP server. Any other DNS resolution method would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer here is "profile that code!". Time how long different parts of the code take so you know where most of the time is spent. That way you'll have a real answer without guesswork.

Still, my guess would be that it is the calls to `smtp_serv.verify(recipient)` may be the slow ones. Reasons might be that the server sometimes needs to ask other SMTP servers for info, or that it does throttling on these operations to avoid having spammers use them massively to gather email addresses.

Also, try pinging the SMTP server. If the ping-pong takes significant time, I would expect sending each email would take at least that long.